# multiply two lists of irregular length

Tags: r, list, mapply, do.call

I have lists like

```
a <- list(list(c(-2,1), 4:5, 2:3), list(c(0,2), c(-1,1)))
b <- list(7:9, c(5,-1))

> a
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] -2  1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] -1  1



> b
[[1]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1]  5 -1
```

I want to multiply each of (-2, 1) from `a[[1]` with 7 from `b[[1]]` to get (-14, 7), each of (4, 5) with 8, each of (2, 3) with 9, and then each of (0, 2) with 5 and finally each of (-1, 1), with -1.

I can be sure that `length(a[[i]])==length(b[[i]])` is `TRUE` for i=1,2 (in practice, i is way larger), so that there are the right number of entries for the desired multiplications.

However, it is not clear how many entries the `a[[i]])` have (in the example, 3 for `a[[1]]` and 2 for `a[[2]]`, or equivalently, how long the `b[[i]]` are), except that they'll have at least one entry. Hence, transforming `a` and `b` into matrices does not seem practical.

I am not sure that is relevant to the problem, but it will also be the case that we have as many entries in each of the `a[[i]])` (i.e., 2) as we have `a[[i]])`s.

I was thinking of some combination of `do.call` and `mapply`, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may indeed use `mapply` (and `Map`, which is the same as `mapply` but with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`). Depending on the format (matrix as in @RonakShah's answer or a list as in your question), you may use

```
Map(mapply, a, b, MoreArgs = list(FUN = `*`))
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  -14   32   18
# [2,]    7   40   27
#
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]   10   -1
```

or

```
Map(Map, a, b, MoreArgs = list(f = `*`))
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] -14   7
#
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 32 40
#
# [[1]][[3]]
# [1] 18 27
#
#
#[[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1]  0 10
#
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1]  1 -1
```

A `tidyverse` alternative to the latter is

```
map2(a, b, map2, `*`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you can ensure `length(a[[i]])==length(b[[i]])` we can use `mapply` inside `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(a), function(x) mapply("*", a[[x]], b[[x]]))


#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  -14   32   18
#[2,]    7   40   27

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]   10   -1
```

Comment: thanks, +1 - allow me to accept the other one given the various options.